# Different behavior with storing a hashed password on local server vs web server?

Tags: php, mysql, hash

So, I have a database of users, and when I register, I hash the password using the hashing algorithm found here - https://defuse.ca/php-pbkdf2.htm

The relevant part of my PHP implementation is here -

```html
$user = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$password = create_hash($password);

$check = false;

if ($stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO USERS (USERNAME, PASSWORDHASH, NAME, EMAIL) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $user, $password, $name, $email);

    /* execute query */
    $check = $stmt->execute();

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}
```

What is strange, is that on my local xampp mySQL server, this stores the passwordhash as something like 7368613235363a313030303a45307775782b2b436651435377...

While on my live mySQL server, it is stored like sha256:1000:6buMj+p6QHQsgz34mF8rcGIWV9wEsVzK:PY4OD...

There is clearly a different pattern there, and my login.php works fine with my local server, but doesn't work on my live server so I believe the problem is here.

Both mySQL store the passwordHash in the same datatype, a binary(64). I believe there is a slight difference in PHP version between the servers but I don't know if that would cause this to happen.

How can I make it so my live web server stores it the same way as my local development server? Or how could I avoid this?

Comment: Just use PHP's `password_hash` and `password_verify` functions.

Comment: Can you find out the php versions running locally vs your server?

Comment: My local server has a version 5.6.11, web server is 5.4.451

Comment: @ceejayoz I switched over to these, however I get an error because these functions are undefined. I believe my web server doesn't have a current enough version of PHP to use them.

Comment: try this [password compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php) if password_hash is not available in your php version;

Comment: @BenMarshall PHP 5.4 has been unsupported for 6 months now and is dangerously insecure to run as a result. You should upgrade (or demand that your host do so). http://php.net/eol.php